# gitlab vs trac: disk usage footprint

Tags: disk-space-utilization, gitlab, trac, request-tracker

I just ragequitted GitHub.

I'm considering between hosting my own issues tracker, or embrace any of gitlab.com, Bitbucket, Sourcehut, etc.

I sorta think either gitlab or trac would be nice, and I couldn't ask which one to choose, in order to avoid opinion polling. However there's some thing... I would really want to use as little persistent storage as possible.

Do you have any data or intuition about relative gitlab "expectable" size bloat relative to trac? (I mean, trac is older, so it's sensible to think it would have somewhat a lower persistent storage footprint) Or gitlab figures relative to any other similar software, or trac figures relative to any other similar software.

Comment: It's going to be really difficult to provide an answer, since it's regarding specific software. Maybe opening a ticket at both GitLab and Trac would help.

Answer (score 2):

[GitLab requirements are documented.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html) Starting at the total size of your repos, and the database at least 10 GB.

Trac doesn't state minimum storage nearly as explicitly, but the same repos + 10 GB seems sane to me.

Of course, do your own capacity planning. Do a rough estimate by multiplying the number of issues expected by a few KB.

If you don't want to store a database, let someone else do it. Both GitLab and Trac have hosted options. Or outsource just PostgreSQL to a managed service.

Comment: "Or outsource just PostgreSQL to a managed service." I only know the products of my particular cloud solutions provider, which wouldn't be fair to promote, but yes it would likely be a PostgreSQL service as much managed as possible. I'm happy to know (only now) that either will sit on PostgreSQL.

Comment: I've had a little _eeek_ moment when I read [trac is lagging in subversion yet](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DevelopmentEnvironmentSetup#DownloadTrac)... that's not a discussion ender, as log shows some activity, but feels somewhat weird.